# Can I one only some columns that was used to create a GBM model and still Predict in Supervised Learning.?

Tags: apache-spark-mllib, h2o, supervised-learning, gbm, sparkling-water

In GBM Model - I have near to 150 columns used to train and create a model - I have a case where for some records I won't be getting all the columns. In that case will the model work - I don't want to set the values to 0 in that case.?

Answer (score 0):

Your question title and description are talking about 2 different things and title is not clear about what you are asking. My following answer is based on your question in description field:

If you use H2O to build your GBM model H2O replaces missing numerical, categorical & unseen values to NA. Please look at the following documentation regarding "handling missing values in GBM" which will help you understand more about your case:

http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/gbm-faq/missing_values.html?highlight=missing%20values

Comment: Sorry that was a typing mistake. I was asking Can I use only some of the columns from the entire set of columns that I used to train data using GBM Model - The reason is we are creating a look alike model in which some of the datasets that we have doesn't have all the columns used to create the model.

Comment: Yes, you can create a new frame based on selecting only interesting columns (let's say you pick top 10 the most important input features) or you can specify option `ignore_columns` option (depends on API you are using)